# Permutations with repetition without two consecutive equal elements

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, permutation

I need a function that generates all the permutation with repetition of an iterable with the clause that two consecutive elements must be different; for example

```
f([0,1],3).sort()==[(0,1,0),(1,0,1)]
#or
f([0,1],3).sort()==[[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]
#I don't need the elements in the list to be sorted.
#the elements of the return can be tuples or lists, it doesn't change anything
```

Unfortunatly itertools.permutation doesn't work for what I need (each element in the iterable is present once or no times in the return)

I've tried a bunch of definitions; first, filterting elements from itertools.product(iterable,repeat=r) input, but is too slow for what I need.

```
from itertools import product
def crp0(iterable,r):
l=[]
for f in product(iterable,repeat=r):
    #print(f)
    b=True
    last=None #supposing no element of the iterable is None, which is fine for me
    for element in f:
        if element==last:
            b=False
            break
        last=element
    if b: l.append(f)
return l
```

Second, I tried to build r for cycle, one inside the other (where r is the class of the permutation, represented as k in math).

```
def crp2(iterable,r):
    a=list(range(0,r))
    s="\n"
    tab="    " #4 spaces
    l=[]
    for i in a:
        s+=(2*i*tab+"for a["+str(i)+"] in iterable:\n"+
        (2*i+1)*tab+"if "+str(i)+"==0 or a["+str(i)+"]!=a["+str(i-1)+"]:\n")
    s+=(2*i+2)*tab+"l.append(a.copy())"
    exec(s)
    return l
```

I know, there's no need you remember me: exec is ugly, exec can be dangerous, exec isn't easy-readable... I know. 
To understand better the function I suggest you to replace exec(s) with print(s).

I give you an example of what string is inside the exec for crp([0,1],2):

```
for a[0] in iterable:
    if 0==0 or a[0]!=a[-1]:
        for a[1] in iterable:
            if 1==0 or a[1]!=a[0]:
                l.append(a.copy())
```

But, apart from using exec, I need a better functions because crp2 is still too slow (even if faster than crp0); there's any way to recreate the code with r for without using exec? There's any other way to do what I need?

Comment: By the way, what you want isn't "Permutations with repetition".

Comment: @EricDuminil I know, but the closest operation to what I need is combination with repetition

Comment: Yes, but it has nothing to do with permutations.

Comment: As I say in my answer, this problem is greater than permutations (some repetition is allowed) but smaller than a repeated product (some repetitions are not allowed). I don't know what a good name would be, so I just call them products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could prepare the sequences in two halves, then preprocess the second halves to find the compatible choices.

```
def crp2(I,r):
    r0=r//2
    r1=r-r0
    A=crp0(I,r0) # Prepare first half sequences
    B=crp0(I,r1) # Prepare second half sequences
    D = {} # Dictionary showing compatible second half sequences for each token 
    for i in I:
        D[i] = [b for b in B if b[0]!=i]
    return [a+b for a in A for b in D[a[-1]]]
```

In a test with iterable=[0,1,2] and r=15, I found this method to be over a hundred times faster than just using crp0.

Comment: I tested by checking the sorted output matched the crp0 version for [0,1,2] and r=15.  Do you have an example where you believe this gives the wrong output?

Comment: Shoot, 1000 apologies. I thought it was recursive, and didn't notice it uses `crp0`. I must have tested it with a modified `crp0`. My bad.

Comment: No problem: (It is also possible you tested with the first revision of this code which was definitely incorrect)

Comment: thanks. At this point your function is the faster, replacing crp0 con crp2 (and of course renaming the function).

Comment: If `r` is even, you could define `B=A`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to return a generator instead of a list. With large values of `r`, your method will take a very long time to process `product(iterable,repeat=r)` and will return a huge list.

With this variant, you should get the first element very fast:

```
from itertools import product

def crp0(iterable, r):
    for f in product(iterable, repeat=r):
        last = f[0]
        b = True
        for element in f[1:]:
            if element == last:
                b = False
                break
            last = element
        if b:
            yield f

for no_repetition in crp0([0, 1, 2], 12):
    print(no_repetition)

# (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
# (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a little bit faster than my crp0, but it's still takes up about 30% time more than crp2. I could implement the generator instead of the list in crp2, but it would be still too much  slow. :(

Comment: ps: of course when misuring the times of execution I reaplaced print(no_rep) with pass

Answer (score 1):

Instead of filtering the elements, you could generate a list directly with only the correct elements. This method uses recursion to create the cartesian product:

```
def product_no_repetition(iterable, r, last_element=None):
    if r == 0:
        return [[]]
    else:
        return [p + [x] for x in iterable
            for p in product_no_repetition(iterable, r - 1, x)
            if x != last_element]

for no_repetition in product_no_repetition([0, 1], 12):
    print(no_repetition)
```

Comment: Generating the correct elements instead of filtering them is exactly the reason why I wrote crp2. But I didn't found out a way without exec. Thanks, I'm going to try

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @EricDuminil's comment that you do not want "Permutations with repetition." You want a significant subset of the product of the iterable with itself multiple times. I don't know what name is best: I'll just call them products.

Here is an approach that builds each product line without building all the products then filtering out the ones you want. My approach is to work primarily with the *indices* of the iterable rather than the iterable itself--and not all the indices, but ignoring the last one. So instead of working directly with `[2, 3, 5, 7]` I work with `[0, 1, 2]`. Then I work with the products of those indices. I can transform a product such as `[1, 2, 2]` where `r=3` by comparing each index with the previous one. If an index is greater than or equal to the previous one I increment the current index by one. This prevents two indices from being equal, and this also gets be back to using all the indices. So `[1, 2, 2]` is transformed to `[1, 2, 3]` where the final `2` was changed to a `3`. I now use those indices to select the appropriate items from the iterable, so the iterable `[2, 3, 5, 7]` with `r=3` gets the line `[3, 5, 7]`. The first index is treated differently, since it has no previous index. My code is:

```
from itertools import product

def crp3(iterable, r):
    L = []
    for k in range(len(iterable)):
        for f in product(range(len(iterable)-1), repeat=r-1):
            ndx = k
            a = [iterable[ndx]]
            for j in range(r-1):
                ndx = f[j] if f[j] < ndx else f[j] + 1
                a.append(iterable[ndx])
            L.append(a)
    return L
```

Using `%timeit` in my Spyder/IPython configuration on `crp3([0,1], 3)` shows `8.54 µs per loop` while your `crp2([0,1], 3)` shows `133 µs per loop`. That shows a sizeable speed improvement! My routine works best where `iterable` is short and `r` is large--your routine finds `len ** r` lines (where `len` is the length of the iterable) and filters them while mine finds `len * (len-1) ** (r-1)` lines without filtering.

By the way, your `crp2()` does do filtering, as shown by the `if` lines in your code that is `exec`ed. The sole `if` in my code does not filter a line, it modifies an item in the line. My code does return surprising results if the items in the iterable are not unique: if that is a problem, just change the iterable to a set to remove the duplicates. Note that I replaced your `l` name with `L`: I think `l` is too easy to confuse with `1` or `I` and should be avoided. My code could easily be changed to a generator: replace `L.append(a)` with `yield a` and remove the lines `L = []` and `return L`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
from itertools import product

result = [ x for x in product(iterable,repeat=r) if all(x[i-1] != x[i] for i in range(1,len(x))) ]
```

Comment: Oh, this list comprehension looks really, really ... _meh_.

Comment: Thanks, but the point isn't a cleaner, more readable, or more synthetic function: all I need is a faster set of instructions. I've tried, but it's slower than what was previously proposed (and also slower than my crp2).

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @peter-de-rivaz's idea (divide and conquer). When you divide the sequence to create into two subsequences, those subsequences are the same or very close. If `r = 2*k` is even, store the result of `crp(k)` in a list and merge it with itself. If `r=2*k+1`, store the result of `crp(k)` in a list and merge it with itself and with `L`.

```
def large(L, r):
    if r <= 4: # do not end the divide: too slow
        return small(L, r)

    n = r//2
    M = large(L, r//2)
    if r%2 == 0:
        return [x + y for x in M for y in M if x[-1] != y[0]]
    else:
        return [x + y + (e,) for x in M for y in M for e in L if x[-1] != y[0] and y[-1] != e]
```

`small` is an adaptation from @eric-duminil's answer using the *famous `for...else` loop of Python*:

```
from itertools import product

def small(iterable, r):
    for seq in product(iterable, repeat=r):
        prev, *tail = seq
        for e in tail:
            if e == prev:
                break
            prev = e
        else:
            yield seq
```

A small benchmark:

```
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: crp2(  [0, 1, 2], 10), number=1000))
#0.16290732200013736
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: crp2(  [0, 1, 2, 3], 15), number=10))
#24.798989593000442

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: large( [0, 1, 2], 10), number=1000))
#0.0071403849997295765
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: large( [0, 1, 2, 3], 15), number=10))
#0.03471425700081454
```