# How can I remove a tuple from a list if the tuple contains two "1" next to each other in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

I have a list of tuples from this:

```
from itertools import product
l1 = list((product((0,1), repeat = n)))
```

For n=4, output is the following:

```
 [(0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 0, 1),
 (1, 0, 1, 0),
 (1, 0, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 0, 0),
 (1, 1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

I want to remove the tuples where at least two "1" are next to each other, for example the `(0,1,1,0)`.

I tried this:

```
for i in l1:
    for j in i:
         if j==1 and j+1 == 1:
                l1.remove(i)
```

I guess this is not working because it takes j+1 as the actual number + 1, like if j=1 it takes as 2 and etc.

What should I do differently?

Comment: `l2 = [v for v in l1 if '11' not in ''.join(list(map(str, v)))]` As long as there's no `11` value in the list

Comment: @ChatterOne Or `[v for v in l1 if '1, 1' not in str(v)]`.

Comment: Related: [Permutations with repetition without two consecutive equal elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44923505/7851470)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach makes logical sense but unfortunately won't work in Python (or most other languages), and the implementation isn't correct because `j==1 and j+1 == 1` is never true; if `j` is equal to 1 then `j+1` is equal to 2, period. But the bigger issue is that you are trying to remove things from a list while iterating over it, [which is a no-no](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260097/12299000).

First let's solve the problem of how to check if two 1s are next to each other. Instead of looking at `j` and `j+1`, we need to look at `t[j]` and `t[j+1]` where `t` is one of the tuples. Also, `j` needs to iterate up to the length minus 1, otherwise `t[j+1]` will give an `IndexError` at the end of the tuple. The `any` function is a convenient way to do this:

```py
any(t[j] == t[j+1] == 1 for j in range(n - 1))
```

Note that `t[j] == t[j+1] == 1` works in Python because of [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

Now let's solve the problem of how to remove such elements from the list. It is much more convenient to simply build a new list with just the elements you want, rather than remove the ones you don't want. A list comprehension is a convenient way to do this:

```py
result = [
    t for t in product((0, 1), repeat=n)
    if not any(t[j] == t[j+1] == 1 for j in range(n - 1))
]
```

Result:

```py
[(0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 1),
 (1, 0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 0, 1),
 (1, 0, 1, 0)]
```

All of that said, for larger n it would be more efficient to use an algorithm which generates only the elements you do want, rather than loop over the whole cartesian product (of size 2<sup>n</sup>) and reject the ones you don't want.

Comment: You're right, of course, although the number of remaining tuples is still [exponential](https://repl.it/repls/PinkLoyalCoderesource), so presumably they can't go very high anyway.

Comment: A non-rejection-based algorithm should still be exponential, but with a lower base (in this case, 1.618 instead of 2), so the improvement is also an exponential factor.

Comment: Yeah, true. I mostly found it funny that yet another famous thing popped up non-obviously :-)

Answer (score 9):

You could build neighbor pairs with `zip(i, i[1:])` and check whether they contain `(1, 1)`:

```
>>> [i for i in l1 if (1, 1) not in zip(i, i[1:])]
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0)]
```

Answer (score 3):

This ought to do the trick:

```py
>>> n = 4
>>> from itertools import product
>>> l1 = list((product((0,1), repeat = n))) 
>>> l1
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]
>>> [t for t in l1 if not any(t[i] == 1 and t[i+1] == 1 for i in range(n-1))]
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0)]
```

The `not any(t[i] == 1 and t[i+1] == 1 for i in range(n-1))` condition basically checks whether consecutive elements are equal to one. Note the `range(n-1)` index iterator - we don't want to check the *n*th element against the *n*+1th element since there isn't a fifth element in any of the tuples above.

**Timing**

Note my function is about twice as slow as [that of Heap Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60546484/5015569).

```py
>>> from time import time as t
>>> def f1():
...     t0 = t()
...     result = [i for i in l1 if (1, 1) not in zip(i, i[1:])]
...     t1 = t()
...     print(t1-t0)
... 
>>> def f2():
...     t0 = t()
...     result = [t for t in l1 if not any(t[i] == 1 and t[i+1] == 1 for i in range(n-1))]
...     t1 = t()
...     print(t1-t0)
... 
>>> l1 = list((product((0,1), repeat = n))) * 1000000
>>> len(l1)
16000000
>>> f1()
8.146391868591309
>>> f2()
18.645386934280396
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a less "pythonic" but more readable example for consideration:

```
def filter_helper(t):
  for i, val in enumerate(t):
    if i != 0 and (t[i-1]) == val and val == 1:
      return False  
  return True

print(list(filter(filter_helper, a)))
```

Where `a` is the original list of tuples.

Comment: @kaya3 Great catch, thanks, added the missing cond.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with forloop and use of python's any() method too

```
for x in l1:
    if any([(x[i]==x[i+1]==1) for i in x]) == True:
        l1.remove(x)
```